# MissingPluginException when using io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

Tags: flutter, sqflite

My Activity class extends io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity so that I can override configureFlutterEngine. When I do so and use sqflite, I get following exception

```
E/flutter (13585): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
```

If switch to io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity, I get no exception, but then I cannot use platform channels that I do in configureFlutterEngine.

I also tried registering through ShimPluginRegistry and get exception as well

```
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(15175): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(15175): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
W/FlutterEngine(15175): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@fb01f2a) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(15175): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
```

This is my Activity class

```
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
   override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
         super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
         GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine))
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you try cold restarting your app?

Comment: Yes, restarted computer, tried different emulator, same thing

Answer (score 2):

First check that the file ***android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java***
is available. 
If it is not created run *flutter clean* and reinstall your sqflite plugin.

If ***GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java*** is created open and check sqflite is added to the plugin list.

```
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
```

Then import GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine) at the MainActivity. Implement it at the start of the configureFlutterEngine() function and it works perfectly.

import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "getEpubs"
    var _eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink? = null

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        //your event channel calls goes below
}
```

This registers the generated sqflite plugin access to the database on the device.

(Sorry for the Kotlin code, but you can change it to Java.)

Don't forget to import: ***io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant*** in your MainActivity.

Answer (score 2):

I run `flutter clean` and then, click to sync gradle again in Android Studio.
It worked to me